# Creating subsets from array of n numbers based on uniqueness level

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, combinations

I'm trying to create a function which will input 4 arguments:

```
function getUniqueSubsets($num_arr, $subset_count, $subset_size, $uniq_level)
```

Where

1. `$num_arr` - array of n numbers.
2. `$subset_size` - subset size
3. `$subset_count` - count of subsets
4. `$uniq_level` - a digit between [1,100] range which will indicate level of unqueness.

So based on $uniq_level, I want to generate number combinations from number array. `$uniq_level` is basically percentage of unique elements on generated set of combinations. So if we want to get 100% unique combinations from given number array, we will give 100 and function has to generate completely unique combinations.

If 1 - there might be lots of repeats.

I wrote a function which generates all possible combinations

```
function combine_all(array $numbers) {
    $count = count($numbers);

    $result = array_map('strval', $numbers);
    for($i = 1; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $combinations = array_slice($result, pow($count, $i-1));
        foreach($numbers as $number) {
            foreach($combinations as $combination) {
                $result[] = $number . ',' . $combination;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I can't figure out, how to achieve uniqueness percentage and what is the most performance efficient way to do this using PHP 7.0.

any suggestions? is there any built-in function of php that might be useful in this situation?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Dan thanks for fast response. So based on $uniq_level, I want to generate number combinations from number array. $uniq_level is basically percentage of unique elements on generated set of combinations. So if we want to get 100 percent unique combinations from given number array, we will give 100 and function has to generate completely unique combinations

Comment: Have you tried anything, or you just want someone to write function for you?

Comment: @PerunSS yes, tried, and wrote it on my question

Comment: @demonoid can original array have multiple occurrences of same number?

Comment: @PerunSS no. original array is completely unique

Comment: @demonoid just one more question, are combinations: 1,3,2 and 1,2,3 different?

Comment: for low uniqueness levels  1,3,2 and 1,2,3  might be good output. as uniqueness rises to 100, repeating numbers gets lesser and lesser. in 100 all combinations have to be completely unique

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131534/discussion-between-demonoid-and-perunss).

Answer (score 1):

I'll post here my idea, it may not be perfect solution.

First, your function is getting all possible subsets of array (n^n) and that is too much, you just need subsets that have size $subset_size. Having you changed function to work this way, here is my solution:

```
function getUniqueSubsets($num_arr, $subset_count, $subset_size, $uniq_level) {
    $candidates = combine_all($arr_num, $subset_size);
    $result = array();
    while ($subset_count > 0 && count($candidates)){
        $possibility = mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax() - 1) / mt_getrandmax() * 100; // this random formula is from some stackoverflow anser
        if ($possibility > $uniq_level){ // your possibility is bigger than uniq_level needed, so you just add random element
            array_push($result, get_random_and_remove($candidates)); // this should be simple function that gets and removes random element from $candidates array.
        }else{
            $element_to_add = get_next_and_remove($candidates, $result); //I'll do explanation of this function later
            if (!$element_to_add) {
                // there is no next uniq element to be added, program should exit and tell user that it cannot get result
                return false;
            }
            array_push($result, $element_to_add)
        }
        $subset_count--;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

`get_random_and_remove` should be easy function to implement. Tricky one is `get_next_and_remove(array $candidates, array $result)`. For this one I'll explain in words how I would do that:

1. randomize $candidates array
2. get and remove next element from it
3. check if that element is unique enough (comparing it with elements from $result array) - this can be done in various way and you need to decide how. My suggestion would be that if both combinations have less than `$subset_size/2 - 1` different elements, they may be called unique.
4. If chosen element is not unique get go to step 2 until you either find unique element and return it, or have no more elements and return false

I haven't written PHP in a while, so sorry for possible mistakes, but this problem is not connected to any language. If you need more help, don't hesitate to ask and I'll expand solution.